# Remove timestamp from date value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a df

```
Begin_Date  Last_date
2010-03-30  NULL
2010-04-07  2010-07-10
```

I want to calculate a column effective last date such that if there is null in last_date column, then I should get today's date (NULL in last_date column means the last date is not yet reached, still active)

```
Begin_Date  Last_date   Effective_date
2010-03-30  NULL           2020-09-08  #Today's date
2010-04-07  2010-07-10     2010-07-10
```

Code:

```
ALTER TABLE df ADD Effective_date AS
     COALESCE(Last_date, GETDATE()) ;
```

Output I am getting:

```
Begin_Date  Last_date   Effective_date
2010-03-30  NULL           2020-09-08 00:00:00:000 Today's date
2010-04-07  2010-07-10     2010-07-10
```

How to remove the 00:00:00:000 part from date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to a `date`:

```
ALTER TABLE random_table_1 ADD effective_end_date AS
     CONVERT(date, COALESCE(End_dt, GETDATE())) ;
```

Comment: can u please change df names etc acc to what i have done...this is to protect privacy

Comment: @noob: names like `df` or `effective_end_date` do not convey any private information. I bet nearly all databases out there have at least one table that has a column named `effective_end_date`

Comment: @noob, while the previous comment is true, the time to think about privacy is before you post. Once you've put data here, it's preserved (and publicly visible) in your edit history.

Comment: And the original version is still available anyway if you look at the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63341347/1), @noob . But a column called `effective_end_date` breaks no privacy laws, I can assure you.